# How to render an RSS feed in a Rails 3.x view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rss, nokogiri, httparty

I have an RSS feed from Zendesk (http://mysupport.zendesk.com/forums/some-path/posts.rss) that I need to render as content on a page on my web app.  **What is the preferred method to pull content in like this?**

At the moment I'm starting to lean to the idea that perhaps my only option is to use Nokogiri or httparty.  Is there a better way?  Either way, would appreciate some directions to point my horse north.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ruby has an RSS Parser built in that you can use.. This code below will cache the results for you as well, and displays the latest 4 items.

```
require 'rss'

Rails.cache.fetch("rss-list") do
  RSS::Parser.parse(open('http://feeds.feedburner.com/your-stuff-here').read, false).items[0..4]
end
```

And so each item could give you a `#title` and `#link` (and more, obviously, like `#description`)

Comment: Thanks! How do you add an expiration on the cache; for example, if I want to regrab content every 30 minutes?

Comment: Additionally, it turns out that this caching portion does fail.  Even in dev mode when I turn on the cache temporarily for testing, I'm getting errors.

Comment: Depends on a number of factors... Maybe remove the cache to simplify. Google for Rails.cache on how to invalidate

Comment: Here's an article to get you started : http://broadcastingadam.com/2011/05/advanced_caching_in_rails